# Debugging BizTalk Exception on Adding Receive Location

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am getting an exception (an error in the Application Log) when enabling a receive location as follows:

> The Messaging Engine failed to add a receive location "My-Receive-Location" with 
>   URL "jms://TestServer:1099/Queue/testQueue/TestClientId/receive/Text" to the 
>   adapter "JNBridge JMS". Reason: "The type initializer 
>   for 'com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectWrapper' threw an exception.".

My research into the JNBridge JMS adapter suggests that `com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectWrapper` often wraps a more informative InnerException.

However, there does not seem to be any way for me to catch this Exception when it is thrown.

My best try so far is to enable the Receive Location in code as follows (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.explorerom.receivelocation(v=bts.20).aspx):

```
private static void EnumerateReceiveLocations()
{
    BtsCatalogExplorer root = new BtsCatalogExplorer();
    try
    {
        root.ConnectionString = "Server=.;Initial Catalog=BizTalkMgmtDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        //Enumerate the receive locations in each of the receive ports.
        foreach (ReceivePort receivePort in root.ReceivePorts)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(receivePort.Name);
            //Enumerate the receive locations.
            foreach (ReceiveLocation location in
               receivePort.ReceiveLocations)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(location.Name);
                if (location.Name == "My-Receive-Location")
                {
                    location.Enable = true;
                    root.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
    catch (Exception e)//If it fails, roll-back all changes.
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

However, this does not throw any exception during execution, and simply raises that same error in the Windows Application Log.

As such, is there any way for me to get further information about an exception thrown during BizTalk receive location enabling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about enabling error logging in the adapter's transport handlers? You can specify a log file name/location and toggle error logging on and off as needed. The error log will contain all nested inner exceptions where you'll find the root cause. Check out the Users' Guide, pg 16 version 2.1. If you are using both send and receive sides of the adapter, configure the error logging in the send and receive transport handlers to point to the same file.

William

Comment: Thanks - logging was configured on both send/receive sides of the adapters but nothing was being logged. I assume this is because the error was happening before the adapter could even be initialised. In any case, some classpath changes and a reboot fixed this particular error. Still no sign of any log messages though for any error that shows.